# What is this animated christmas TV Movie about a sentient ornament?

Tags: identify-this-movie, animation

I have vague memories of a TV movie from the late nineties about a sentient Christmas decoration.  It was called something like "the Littlest Christmas Ball."  In terms of plot, I have nothing, but I think it took place largely on a Christmas tree and there might have been an angel ornament.

Comment: If you hadn't mentioned that it took place on a tree I would have guessed this was the tear-jerker made for TV Hallmark[TM] movie: "The Christmas Shoes"

Comment: Definitely not "The Christmas Shoes."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the movie you're thinking of is Noel. I was looking for something extremely similar and that's what I found. You can watch it here: